# How to draw alternatives in sequence diagram using www.websequencediagrams.com tool

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, multiple-choice

I am using https://www.websequencediagrams.com/ to draw a sequence diagram and I need to handle a multiple choice case.
Could somebody please specify how it is possible to draw alternatives using this tool?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `alt` in sequence diagram to represent multiple choice case.

[image: sequence diagram with alt]

Below is a snippet with `alt`,

```
A->B: action

alt choice A
    A->B: action 1
else choice B
    A->B: action 2
else choice C
    A->B: action 3
end
```